# Separate HTML document

Tags: html, xml, r, xpath, html-parsing

I am working with the XML library in R and would like to separate a HTML in chunks

```
myHTML <- htmlTreeParse("myHTMLfile.HTML", useInternal=T)
unlist(xpathApply(myHTML, '//div', xmlValue))
```

This works fine and gives me one long vector of strings for the entire thing. However, ideally I'd like to split up my HTML in chunks. The HTML structure is the following:

```
    <DOC>
       <div>
           Document 1 - Element 1
       </div>

       <div>
           Document 1 - Element 2
       </div>

       <div>
           Document 1 - Element 3
       </div>

    </DOC>

    <DOC>
       <div>
           Document 2 - Element 1
       </div>

       <div>
           Document 2 - Element 2
       </div>

       <div>
           Document 2 - Element 3
       </div>

    </DOC>
```

So I would like to have a list, where each element corresponds to the content in one  , and the elements of each list are string vectors, containing Element 1, 2, 3 for each DOC.

I struggle to (A) even query 'DOC' because it is not part of the namespace?? and (B) get this kind of list of string vectors output.

so instead of this output

```
[1] "Document 1 - Element 1"
[2] "Document 1 - Element 2"
[3] "Document 1 - Element 3"
[4] "Document 2 - Element 1"
[5] "Document 2 - Element 2"
[6] "Document 2 - Element 3"
```

I am looking to get this:

```
[[1]]
    [1] "Document 1 - Element 1"
    [2] "Document 1 - Element 2"
    [3] "Document 1 - Element 3"
[[2]]
    [1] "Document 2 - Element 1"
    [2] "Document 2 - Element 2"
    [3] "Document 2 - Element 3"
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is an example of the html file I'd like to process:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sytpp/sample-files/master/data_3.html
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

```
library(XML)
dd<-xmlInternalTreeParse("<DOCS><DOC>
       <div>Document 1 - Element 1</div>
       <div>Document 1 - Element 2</div>
       <div>Document 1 - Element 3</div>
</DOC><DOC>
       <div>Document 1 - Element 3</div>
       <div>Document 1 - Element 3</div>
       <div>Document 1 - Element 3</div>
</DOC></DOCS>")


xmlApply(dd["//DOC"], function(x) xpathSApply(x,".//div", xmlValue))
```

We find all the DOC elements and then find all the divs for each DOC so we combine the outer `xmlApply` to find the `DIV` elements with the inner `xpathSApply` to extract the text from the `div`

Comment: yes, the example makes complete sense but when I apply it to my html, I get an empty list(). Can I share a real example html with 3 <DOC> elements with you?

Comment: It would be better if you just updated your question with sample data that more accurately reflected your situation.

Comment: I added a link to the file, its a download from LexisNexis: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sytpp/sample-files/master/data_3.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
dat <- c("Document 1 - Element 1",
 "Document 1 - Element 2",
 "Document 1 - Element 3",
 "Document 2 - Element 1",
 "Document 2 - Element 2",
 "Document 2 - Element 3")

split(dat, sapply(strsplit(dat, " - " ), "[", 1))

## $`Document 1`
## [1] "Document 1 - Element 1"
## [2] "Document 1 - Element 2"
## [3] "Document 1 - Element 3"
## 
## $`Document 2`
## [1] "Document 2 - Element 1"
## [2] "Document 2 - Element 2"
## [3] "Document 2 - Element 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility.  We can use `readHTMLList` as the function call in `getNodeSet`

```
library(XML)
getNodeSet(xmlParseString(txt), "//DOC", fun = readHTMLList)
#[[1]]
#[1] "Document 1 - Element 1" "Document 1 - Element 2" "Document 1 - Element 3"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "Document 2 - Element 1" "Document 2 - Element 2" "Document 2 - Element 3"
```

Or we could also try

```
lapply(xmlParseString(txt)["DOC"], readHTMLList)
# $DOC
# [1] "Document 1 - Element 1" "Document 1 - Element 2"
# [3] "Document 1 - Element 3"
# 
# $DOC
# [1] "Document 2 - Element 1" "Document 2 - Element 2"
# [3] "Document 2 - Element 3"
```

where `txt` is

```
txt <- "<DOC>\n       <div>\n           Document 1 - Element 1\n       </div>\n\n       <div>\n           Document 1 - Element 2\n       </div>\n\n       <div>\n           Document 1 - Element 3\n       </div>\n\n    </DOC>\n\n    <DOC>\n       <div>\n           Document 2 - Element 1\n       </div>\n\n       <div>\n           Document 2 - Element 2\n       </div>\n\n       <div>\n           Document 2 - Element 3\n       </div>\n\n    </DOC>"
```

From your given url, I was able to get the following result

```
library(RCurl)
content <- getURL(url)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(content, useInternal=TRUE)
values <- getNodeSet(doc, "//div", fun = xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
str(values[1:6])
# List of 6
# $ : chr "1 of 3 DOCUMENTS"
# $ : chr "The Daily Telegraph (London)"
# $ : chr "November 1, 2014 Saturday  Edition 1; National Edition"
# $ : chr "THE WEEK IN WESTMINSTER"
# $ : chr "SECTION: FEATURES; Pg. 26"
# $ : chr "LENGTH: 500 words"
length(values)
#[1] 39
```